# Unexplainable differences between Java on OSX and Blade VPS

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm developing a Tomcat Web Application. I'm using apache-tomcat-9.0.10 on both my development machine (Mac OS High Sierra) and my Blade VPS (Debian 8.1). Both give the following output on java -version:

Local:

> java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3
>   (build 10.0.1+10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build
>   10.0.1+10, mixed mode) Evert-Jans-MacBook-Pro:apache-tomcat-9.0.10

Remote:

> java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3
>   (build 10.0.1+10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build
>   10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

The Java settings are equal on both my Local machine and the remote VPS.

Yet, Locally it works but the remote server gives a 'page can’t be found error'.

Any ideas? Please let me know.

Comment: looks like the problem is not related to the java's version :) Search elsewhere

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Check Tomcat config files. Check WAR file unpacked. Check ono-WAR libraries. Check the log files. Turn up the logging level. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I didn't upload the Lucene index which the app expected under/usr/local/index/.

Apache Tomcat could have given a more descriptive error than 404, which caused me to go and seek in the wrong direction.